# SWIFT still fighting to assign a value to a nested array within a class

Tags: arrays, swift, class, nested, initialization

This carries on my last question [struggling with value assignment to optional class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62130016/swift-struggling-with-value-assignment-to-optional-class-variable), for which David provided me a good hint to a similar problem. 
After numerous iterations I now came up with a different approach, however, it still fails and I have no idea why (and basically what happens)

I have the class definitions

```swift
struct HighScores: Codable {
    var Scores:Int
    var highscoreRecord: [HighscoreRecord]
}

struct HighscoreRecord: Codable {
    var Rank:Int
    var Date:String?
    var avDuration:Float?
    var Score:Int?
    var Tries:Int?
}
```

In the view controller I have declared a variable of type HighScores, which may read the data from a JSON file or which may be initialized when setting the first high score.

```swift
class GameplayViewController: UIViewController {

    var jsonResult: HighScores?

   ...

    if firstHighscore == 1 {
        jsonResult?.Scores = 1
        jsonResult?.highscoreRecord.append(HighscoreRecord(Rank: 1, Date: formatter.string(from: dateStart), avDuration: Float(lblSpeed.text ?? "0.0"), Score: Int(lblRatio.text ?? "0"), Tries: hits + misses))
...
    print(jsonResult)
```

This compiles and also runs. However, if I monitor the jsonResult variable, it still shows nil after assigning the Scores and and highscoreRecord values.

What happens, why can I assign a value without an error and without actually assigning it?
And first and foremost, how do I get my values into jsonResult?

Cheers

Comment: You still haven't given `jsonResult` a value since your last question so it is still nil. You need to do `jsonResult = ...`.

Comment: What happens here is that when using the `?` in `jsonResult?.Scores = 1` is that you are saying that _if_ jsonResult is not nil then assign 1 to `Scores` otherwise do nothing so the compiler or runtime has nothing to complain about since the code is correct. So you need to investigate where in your code you need to instantiate the `jsonResult` property

Comment: Before coming up with the code above, I tried numerous variations of
jsonResult?.highscoreRecord = [HighscoreRecord]()

Comment: Before coming up with the code above, I tried numerous variations of
jsonResult?.highscoreRecord = [HighscoreRecord](), none of them being successful. So I was quite happy that the code above did not throw an error. So how would I pass an initial value to jsonResult given the class structure behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So following on from the comments above if you changed the code to be something along the lines of this you create the instance of the struct and add the values.

```swift
var jsonResult: HighScores?

    if firstHighscore == 1 {
        jsonResult = HighScores(Scores: 1, highscoreRecord: [HighscoreRecord(Rank: 1, Date: "your date", avDuration: 0.0, Score: 0, Tries: 0)])
    }
```

once created you can add more highscorerecords to the array as needed, using the append method.

Comment: Now I see! Thanks a lot!